# How to clear the email and password value on logout + Angularjs + Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I am using the below code to logout.

```
$scope.logout = function () {
      $window.localStorage.clear();
      $rootScope.$new(true);
      $scope.$new(true);
      $state.go("home");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have ng-models on the email and password fields you can just clean the variables in the scope.

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="email">
<input type="password" ng-model="password">
```

JS:

```
$scope.email = '';
$scope.password = '';
```

Comment: Well, the js should go inside your logout function

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$scope.logOut = function(){
    console.log('invoking logout function');
    $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
        //now you can clear history or goto another state if you need
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });            
    });
  };
```

For more information about clearing history refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).

check this question that gives you some [idea](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clear-navigation-history-prevent-back-button-use-android/1458) .